# SSHTunnel searching for default private key (id_rsa) instead of the ssh_pkey I specify

Tags: python-3.x, ssh-tunnel

I am using MacOS and something in my system config keeps telling python's `SSHTunnelForwarder` to use my default `id_rsa` file INSTEAD of the file I specify in the configuration below:

```
>>> from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
>>> db_tunnel = SSHTunnelForwarder(
...     ssh_host="localhost",
...     ssh_username="username",
...     ssh_port=1111,
...     ssh_pkey="~/.ssh/test",
...     remote_bind_address=("my-remote-database-domain", 3306)
... )
```

Gives me this error message:
`2022-03-23 13:15:35,715| ERROR   | Password is required for key /Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa`

Where can I edit the config to override this search for the wrong key?

My `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host *
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/test
```

And yes, I have run `ssh-add ~/.ssh/test` to add this key.

What else could be confusing it?

Answer (score 1):

I got rid of those messages `ERROR   | Password is required for key /Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa` (I would get more than one since I have several keys) by using the option

```
host_pkey_directories=[]
```

In the [docs](https://sshtunnel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=connect#sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder) it says:

> host_pkey_directories (list) – Look for pkeys in folders on this list,
> for example [‘~/.ssh’].
>
> Default: None (disabled)

but even setting `host_pkey_directories=None` didn't help.

Here's a working demo:

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder

remote_host = my_remote_host
username = my_remote_username
private_key_path = "/Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa"
private_key_passphrase = "xxxx"

my_tunnel = SSHTunnelForwarder(
                ssh_address_or_host=remote_host,
                ssh_username=username,
                ssh_pkey=private_key_path,
                ssh_private_key_password=private_key_passphrase,
                host_pkey_directories=[],
                local_bind_address=('localhost', 5000),
                remote_bind_address=('localhost', 8080)
            )
my_tunnel.start()
print("Is active? {}".format(my_tunnel.is_active))
print(my_tunnel.tunnel_bindings)
```

Notes:

- the connection worked for me despite the error messages
- working on a Mac

Answer (score -1):

This error message doesn't matter if you have assigned other keys to create the connection, you can insert more logs to confirm that your program has continued to run.

And make sure the host in your MySQL connect parameter must be 127.0.0.1 :

```
db = pymysql.connect(host="127.0.0.1",
                             user=user,
                             password=password,
                             database='db', port= db_tunnel.local_bind_port)
```

Comment: It seems like the function should use the pkey it gets passed. Is there at least a way to silence this error (since it's not really an error)?

Comment: if you have an id_dsa key file in your ~/.ssh dir and you do NOT need it, try renaming it to something else, or delete it entirely.

Comment: I think this does not address the issue.  I also would like the error to not occur (and be suppressed) rather than say "well it's okay it works anyway!"

Comment: This now throws an error and kills my script. I also just had this start to impact me after updating. Anyone aware if there is a version that does not have this issue?