# sshtunnel is not using specified key and not using private key password

Tags: python, mysql, ssh

I'm writing a script that needs to connect to a MySQL server via SSH. I have the following:

```
import mysql.connector
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder


def query_mysql_server(query):
    with SSHTunnelForwarder(
        ('ssh_server_ip', 22),
        ssh_username='sshuser',
        ssh_pkey='/Users/myhomedir/.ssh/id_rsa',
        ssh_private_key_password='my_ssh_key_passphrase',
        remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 3306)
    ) as server:

        conn = mysql.connector.connect(
            host='127.0.0.1',
            port=server.local_bind_port,
            user='mysqluser',
            password='mysqluserpass',
            database='mydb'
        )

        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query)

        results = cursor.fetchall()
        for row in results:
            print(row)

        cursor.close()
        conn.close()

query = "SELECT * FROM users;"
query_mysql_server(query)
```

Running this results in the error `ERROR   | Password is required for key /Users/myhomedir/.ssh/id_rsa`.
I've also tried using a different key (`/Users/myhomedir/.ssh/app_key`), that doesn't have a pass phrase set at all and get exactly the same error, referring to the "default" key `id_rsa`, so an alternative key is not picked up for some reason.

Both keys are added to the ssh authentication agent using `ssh-add`. The default key (id_rsa) is an RSA key, not an OpenSSH key.

System is macOS.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: After troubleshooting it further and trying invalid SSH credentials I realized that the SSH tunnel actually works and the code hung on `mysql.connector.connect` until I added `use_pure=True`. Seemingly this error shows up always, regardless if the connection succeeds or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After troubleshooting it further and trying invalid SSH credentials I realized that the SSH tunnel actually works and the code hung on `mysql.connector.connect` until I added `use_pure=True`. Seemingly this error shows up always, regardless if the connection succeeds or not.
The `ssh_pkey` also works as intended and will use the specified key file, but will still raise the error in question quoting the "default" key `id_rsa`.

Same issue is described here: [SSHTunnel searching for default private key (id_rsa) instead of the ssh_pkey I specify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71592943/sshtunnel-searching-for-default-private-key-id-rsa-instead-of-the-ssh-pkey-i-s)

Answer (score 1):

##### Basic Requirements

Did you verify, that the connection succeeds on the commandline?

I've already [described it here for scp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75814504/transfer-a-file-via-scp-with-key-auth/75815045#75815045), but that's almost ssh without shell and the required prerequisites are identical as they are here.

Essentially I miss, that you state:

- the program runs using the same user credentials as the user that has added the key to the ssh-agent.
- There has been (by the same user) made a first connection, so the host-key is known and verified
- The public key of the authentication key is transfered to the user-home on the server and added to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

You also should be verifying that the access rights are restricted as required:

```
700   ~/.ssh/
600   all private keys
664   at least, better 640 or more restricted the other files
```

##### Undesired Fallback to id_rsa

As you state the basic config is done and rechecked and also the connection directly via the shell is fine, a single detail remains:

Have these successful shell checks been done with the `app_key` or with the default `id_rsa`?

If also the connect via the `app_key` succeeds, these 'basics' are done.
Else *if the `app_key` fails at the shell* the key-type and key-length would be of interest.
Also so a check of the `~/.ssh/config` would be of interest. But the priority lays on the log files:

The key-choice might be influenced by the answers of the ssh server:

```
HostbasedAcceptedKeyTypes
```

This config can be requested by the client:

```
ssh -Q HostbasedAcceptedKeyTypes <server>
```

##### Server Log

To enhance the log output the log-level should be set it to or `DEBUG` (up to `DEBUG3`is possible)

File: server:/etc/ssh/ssh**d**_config

```
LogLevel DEBUG
```

##### Client Log

Also the client's log-entries for the whole authentication process would be helpfull.

At your MAC please choose "All Messages" in your Console.app

##### Auth-Error:

Here `man ssh` reveals a risk for a problem:

> SSH_ASKPASS
> If ssh needs a passphrase, it will read the passphrase from the current terminal if it was run from a terminal.  If ssh does not have a terminal associated with it but DISPLAY and SSH_ASKPASS are set, it will execute the program specified by SSH_ASKPASS and open an X11 window to read the passphrase.  This is particularly useful when calling ssh from a .xsession or related script.  (***Note that on some machines it may be necessary to redirect the input from /dev/null to make this work.***)

Perhaps you put an eye on this?

Comment: Hi @dodrg. Connection works just fine from the shell. 1) I'm running the python script as the same user that owns the SSH key. 2) The public key is in the authorized_keys file on the remote server under the user I'm connecting as. 3) Verified and adjusted file permissions as per your comment. Same result.

Comment: Answer updated, Essentially the server log should be helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

What helped me was setting

```
host_pkey_directories=[]
```

(see [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77869422/2314737)).

I believe this prevents the `SSHTunnelForwarder` from trying to authenticate with more than one key.